# angularjs custom filter vs selection lists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 6 select lists as the number of options i have and each has 6 options , when i select one options the rest of the section list must not contain the selected anymore

**html**

```
  <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
 <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item as item.type for item in filters|filterFnt:selected" ng-click="addProperty(selected)"></select>
```

**js**

```
$scope.selectionList  = [] ;
$scope.selected       = $scope.filters[0];


    $scope.addProperty  = function (obj) {
         var index = $scope.selectionList.indexOf(obj);
         if( index == -1) {
             $scope.selectionList.push(obj);
         }
    };
$scope.filters      = [
        {
            type : 'select one',
            inputType : '111',
        },
        {
            type : 'A',
            inputType : '111',
        },
        {
            type: 'B',
            Xtype : '222'
        },
        {
            type: 'C',
            Xtype: '444' ,
      },
        {
            type: 'D',
            Xtype : '555'

        },
        {
            type: 'E',
            Xtype : '6666'

        }, 
        {
            type: 'F',
            inputType : '777'

        }

    ];    



app.filter('filterFnt', function() {

          return function(input,x) {
            angular.forEach($scope.selectionList, function(item) {
                var index = input.indexOf(item);
                   if( index != -1 && item != x) {
                     input.splice(index, 1);     
                }
            });
            return input

          };
      });
```

**issue**

when i select an option from select list i want to keep that option in the list , what is happening it is being removed from the current one as well

Thank you

Comment: can you provide plunker with sample?

Comment: @Grundy it is a part of big module i think it will be hard to post , can you help me with the current info ? note that these are raw data provided

Comment: now not clear how it should work: seems you have a error when use `$scope.selectionList` inside filter without injecting `scope`

Comment: can you explain what you expect and what you have now? and what is wrong?

Comment: @Grundy Thanks , 6 select lists with 6 options inside each 
, default value of each select option is "select one"
when i select an option from first select list ,the selected option must be removed from the rest .
current situation : selected value is being removed from all including the current select list leaving it's selected option to blank

Comment: now it removing from all because you use one list for all sekects, so when you do splice in filter, you change source array

Comment: can i remove it from all except the current one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76897/discussion-between-grundy-and-rawan-nj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in [*splice*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function inside filter: it function change source array, so on every filter changed data for all selects.
Instead [*splice*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you can use simple [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Your filter can be like

```
app.filter('filterFnt', function() {
  return function(input, selectionList, selectionObj, filterType) {
    //get elements that selected in current select, or not already selected
    return input.filter(function(el) {
      return selectionObj[filterType] === el || (selectionList.indexOf(el) == -1);
    });
  };
});
```

I add *selectionObj*, this object contain selected item for current select.

Before adding element in *selectionList* you need remove already added item from current select like

```
function removeFromSelected(currType){
    var o = $scope.selectionObj[currType],
        index = $scope.selectionList.indexOf(o);

    if (index != -1)
      $scope.selectionList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  function removeFromSelected(currType){
      var o = $scope.selectionObj[currType],
          index = $scope.selectionList.indexOf(o);
    
      if (index != -1)
        $scope.selectionList.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $scope.addProperty = function(obj, currType) {
    removeFromSelected(currType);
    if (!obj) {
      delete $scope.selectionObj[currType];
    } else {
      var index = $scope.selectionList.indexOf(obj);
      
      $scope.selectionList.push(obj);
      $scope.selectionObj[currType] = obj;
    }

  };

  $scope.filters = [{
    type: 'A',
    inputType: '111',
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    Xtype: '222'
  }, {
    type: 'C',
    Xtype: '444',
  }, {
    type: 'D',
    Xtype: '555'
  }, {
    type: 'E',
    Xtype: '6666'
  }, {
    type: 'F',
    inputType: '777'
  }];
  $scope.selectionList = [];
  $scope.selectionObj = {};
});

app.filter('filterFnt', function() {

  return function(input, selectionList, selectionObj, filterType) {
    return input.filter(function(el) {
      return selectionObj[filterType] === el || (selectionList.indexOf(el) == -1);
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item as item.type for item in filters|filterFnt:selectionList:selectionObj:filter.type" ng-change="addProperty(selected,filter.type)">
      <option value="">select one</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  selectionList - {{selectionList}}
</div>
```